# with the background-position property, where is the 50% position decision?

Tags: css

in the following example an image created with background-image has an even width (4 pixels) .

It is placed in the middle (50%) of the div element containing it. This element has an odd size (9pixels).

result:
the image has 3 pixels to its left and 2 to its right.
it could have been 2 pixels to its left and 3 to its right.

My question is not why. My question is where are the documents that specify this type of CSS decision?

```css
#a {
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red,red);
  width: 9px;
  height: 10px;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  background-color: black;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 4px 6px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: this is not a CSS decision but a browser implementation

Comment: does that mean it depends on the browser?

Comment: and probably your OS, you monitor resolution, etc .. you are far from the CSS world.

Comment: not so far :) https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/7982#issue-1428369011

Comment: @TemaniAfif your answer was correct, I admit I was a bit skeptical :) https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/7982#issuecomment-1301186171